# Set docker compose ARGS from an env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, arguments

I have a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` file.
For both, I want to use the `.env.local` env file

Here is the file tree:

```
|-- .env
|-- .env.local
|-- docker
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- docker-compose.yml
```

Here is the command to build the image:

`docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml build`

I want to pass the proxy values existing in my `.env.local` to the `Dockerfile`
Here are the content of every file.

```
> cat .env
HTTP_PROXY=127.27.0.1:8080
HTTPS_PROXY=127.27.0.1:8080
```

```
> cat .env.local
HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:9090
HTTPS_PROXY=127.0.0.1:9090
```

```
> cat docker/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - ../.env.local
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - HTTP_PROXY
        - HTTPS_PROXY
```

```
> cat docker/Dockerfile
FROM php:8.1-fpm-bullseye

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

ARG HTTP_PROXY
ARG HTTPS_PROXY

ENV http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}
ENV https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY}

RUN printenv
```

**There is a command in my `Dockerfile` that prints the env vars, The values are taken from the `.env` file instead of `.env.local`**

How can I correct that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `env_file` option, docker compose injects enviromental variables to the *running* container.

As a result when you run `printenv`, in the build phase you do not get the result you expected.

If you want to pass environmental variables to the `build phase`, I would recommend removing the `env_file` option

Instead, run

```
source .env.local
```

The variables are now available to your `bash` as enviromental variables

Then run the following build command

```
docker-compose build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY
```

Now compose **knows** their values at the build phase and can be passed to your docker build.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - HTTP_PROXY
        - HTTPS_PROXY
```